# divide every row by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to divide every row until the last row but I am stuck at dividing by just one row which is row 2. I was thinking of using this

```
Dim LastRow As Range

LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

But my knowledge on how to make use of the range is very limited.

Do share your thoughts.. thanks! :)

My code is as follows:

```
Sub test1()


For Each c In Range("AL2:AS2 , BC2 ")
c.Value = c.Value / 1000
Next c
```

End Sub

Comment: nothing wrong with your `test1`, note `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` you used returns the Last Used row, if it is not a number then it fails. LastRow should be type `Long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the range by building the range string, like this:

```
Range("AL2:AS" & LastRow & ", BC2:BC" & LastRow)
```

Notice that the `.Row` property of Range returns a `Long` which is the row number, so you have to declare :

```
 Dim LastRow As Long
```

Finally this gives :

```
Sub test2()

 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim myCell As Range

 LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For Each myCell In Range("AL2:AS" & LastRow & ", BC2:BC" & LastRow)
  myCell.Value = myCell.Value / 1000
 Next myCell
End Sub
```